# Why it is required to get clock information of system bus in linux Network driver?

Tags: c, arm, linux-device-driver, network-driver

I am going through network driver source and find this in probe function

```
    priv->busclk = devm_clk_get(&pdev->dev, "ahb2_gmac");
    if (IS_ERR(priv->busclk)) {
            ret = PTR_ERR(priv->busclk);
            dev_err(&pdev->dev, "Cannot get AHB clock err=%d\n", ret);
            return ret;
    }
    ret = clk_prepare_enable(priv->busclk);
    if (ret != 0) {
            dev_err(&pdev->dev, "Cannot prepare_enable busclk\n");
            return ret;
    }

    cr = clk_get_rate(priv->miiclk);
    dev_info(&pdev->dev, "Current MII clkrate %lu\n", cr);

    ret = clk_set_rate(priv->miiclk, cr / 4);
```

In first statement devm_clk_get(&pdev->dev, "ahb2_gmac"),
  we are getting Bus(AHB2) clock and here clk_get_rate(priv->miiclk), we are getting the mii interterface clock

What purpore it serves (getting the bus and mii clock), how it helps in proper emac operations?

Comment: The hardware might need to know the frequency of the clocks to calibrate its internal clock that it uses to calculate the transmission speeds?

Comment: This is probably specified in the datasheet for one of the pieces of hardware involved.

Comment: It could be as simple as just making sure the device is clocked (via the enable call) so that you don't deadlock the system trying to access it. Without knowing if and where the `busclk` variable itself is actually used for anything, it's kinda hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

It is getting the device clock settings specified in the DTB and enabling and setting the device clock rate to the same. Without enabling the clocks, the peripheral will not function. For details of the final clock rate setting, you might need to have a look at the data sheet